# Rails: send_data() takes 120 seconds to send tiny file to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I encounter a strange Problem with Rails3 and `send_data`. A simple controller action should just send a small file to the browser:

```
def download
  send_data "test", :filename => "file.txt", :type => 'text/plain'
end
```

When I click the link to that controller action in the browser nothing happens for almost exactly 120 seconds. After these 120 seconds the file will be downloaded instantly.

The strange thing is, that I can keep on browsing on the other sites of the web app and everything responds within milliseconds. The logfile shows

```
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data file.txt (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

Just when i clicked the download link. Nothing is printed to the logfile after theses 120 seconds have passed and the file is actually send to the browser.

I am using Rails 3.0.7, POW and Mongrel on Mac OS X. Tested with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hmmm. When i start my server with `rails server` (not using POW) everythings works fine. Even with Mongrel or Webrick. So POW is the problem?

Comment: See: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a POW-Problem. A workaround is to use Mongrel or Webrick.

See: github.com/37signals/pow/issues/102